# Failed to convert drawable into a drawable

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview

I'm getting the error "Failed to convert @drawable/12234 into a drawable" where 12234 is my image name, that is placed inside the drawable folder.

I'm able to assign other images that are smaller, however when I try to assign this image it gives me an error.

Here is my code for my Imageview xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/12234"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

Comment: Change the image name to all lower case letters with no spaces and try again

Comment: I just figured that out, thanks for your response though!

Comment: apart from the answers here avoid including the file extension

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to documentation drawables resources must satisfy the following:

`File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or _.`

And also in your case it cannot be all numbers, it has to have at least one letter.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by renaming the image to have a character first.

Changed image name from 12234.jpg to r12234.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In Adroid Studio's Design View, try just clicking the refresh icon, the one that looks like two curved arrows facing each other.
This worked for me - I didn't need to rename anything or restart my computer.
I'm running ver 1.5.1, Marshmallow, API 23.

Comment: This should be comment

Answer (score 0):

I have been stumbling for many hours, read almost all answers on all questions but nothing worked. Finally, I have found a solution that worked.

What i did

- Showed "drawable" in explorer
- Replaced ALL ı's with i's (drawable-hdpı -> drawable-hdpi, renamed
  all folders)   Then the folders didn't appear in android studio
- Replaced only 2 i's with ı's (drawable-hdpi -> drawable-hdpı, renamed
  2 folders)   Afterwards, all the images started to appear and finally
  i was able to add images.